# Member Feed in Mongo DB

Tags: php, mongodb

Which is better in MongoDB to do for member_feed Collection ?

```
   {
   "member_id": "153442",
   "recent_activity": {
     "content_id": "196004",
     "content_type_id": "10",
     "social_network_id": "9",
  },
   "_id": ObjectId("5352958667fa3812548e65da"),
   "_type": {
     "0": "Altibbi_Mongo_MemberFeed" 
  }
```

And repeat this object but with different **"recent_activity "** Object each time an activity happen in social network ,**OR** to build 1 Document for each member like this and array of recent activity objects

```
  {
       "member_id": "153442",
       "recent_activity": {
         "content_id": "196004",
         "content_type_id": "10",
         "social_network_id": "9",
      },
        "recent_activity": {
         "content_id": "196005",
         "content_type_id": "10",
         "social_network_id": "9",
      },
          "recent_activity": {
         "content_id": "196004",
         "content_type_id": "10",
         "social_network_id": "9",
      },


       "_id": ObjectId("5352958667fa3812548e65da"),
       "_type": {
         "0": "Altibbi_Mongo_MemberFeed" 
      }
```

Which is better For IO , Inserting , Updating and Selecting . I am using beanstalkd for queuing ?

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a lot of activity records per user you should store it in separate documents (and not in an array as part of one document). Reason: there is a hard limit on document size (16MB).

Comment: but writing so much records it cost me size and high IO, sharding will solve the problem ?